# FSQRT using FLD and using FILD

Tags: assembly, x86, fpu, x87

i can't understand how to use FSQRT with float numbers, how to convert this number to show in the screen

```
.data
valor dword 49
.code
fild dword ptr [valor]
fsqrt
fistp dword ptr [valor]
mov ax,word ptr valor
```

it returns 7, that's ok, sqrt(49)=7
but with fld, doesnt know, how to get value..

```
fld dword ptr [valor]
fsqrt
fstp dword ptr [valor]
mov ax,word ptr valor
```

it doesnt return 7, but some number 463365205
how can i get the right value?

Comment: Try `fild` to load an integer.  Similarly, use `fistp` to store an integer.

Comment: with fild it works... my problems is how to use real numbers, in my code i need sqrt(7), how i can use in assembly ... fistp returns 3, i need to "use" 2,6457

Comment: For floating point numbers, `fld` and `fstp` are correct, but note that you need to treat them differently than integers as they don't work the same way.  For example, write `valor dword 49.0` to make `valor` a floating point number.

Comment: thanks, i will use "valor dword 54.0", but when i do "fld dword [valor] / fsqrt / fstp dword [valor]" i like to put this value in a TextBox... i can show in textbox "7" for result of sqrt(49), but i cant show 7.3484 in the textbox (for result sqaure root 54).... can u help me?

Comment: You need a routine that converts the floating point number to string.  Writing one is quite tricky.  If you are using some sort of library, there might be a function that does that for you.  Otherwise, you might need to write your own.

Comment: You can use `sprintf` to format a `double` into a string of ASCII digits.

Comment: `463365205` is greater than 65535; it's not a possible integer value for AX.  Did you maybe declare it in C as returning `unsigned` instead of `unsigned short`?  Leaving the high half of EAX unmodified (holding whatever garbage the caller left there), and replacing the low half with the low 16 bits of the mantissa bit-pattern like you're doing, could explain that.

Comment: @PeterCordes is greater than 65535 but it should represent "7"... because sqrt(49)=7.. maybe problem is "dword", i can use "real4" or another data type.. no eax, because i am in 16 bits windows